# Tkinter destroy and quit freezes root window on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

When pressing the button from the code below the window freezes and the spinning ball of death appears. Same issue arises with `quit`. I'm running python 3.7 with tk version 8.6 on MacOS 10.14.3.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text="Quit", command=root.destroy).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't duplicate your problem with python 3.7 on osx 10.14. When I run your program from the command line and click the button, the program exits exactly as it should. Are you certain _this exact program_ exhibits this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling python?

Answer (score 3):

root.quit is what you should use to close the main (root) window of your application.

the issues you are seeing are likely because you are running your code from an IDE. 
[such as Spyder for instance, which I happen to know first-hand hangs tkinter applications on root.quit()]

run your program from a terminal prompt, and you should have no issues.

IMPORTANT:
Also, be sure you are using tk version 8.6.8, as version 8.6.9 has known issues with MacOS 10.14 Mojave.
https://bugs.python.org/issue35402
https://bugs.python.org/issue35485